# Where could be the best place to check a relation?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 8.

I have this route :

```
Route::apiResource('organizations/{organization}/site-types', SiteTypeController::class)->whereUuid(['organization', 'site_type']);
```

And this controller (example for the destroy) :

```
public function __construct(SiteTypeRepository $siteTypeRepository)
    {
        $this->siteTypeRepository = $siteTypeRepository;
        $this->authorizeResource(SiteType::class, 'site_type');
    }

public function destroy(Organization $organization, SiteType $siteType)
    {
        $this->siteTypeRepository->deleteSiteType($siteType);

        return response()->noContent();
    }
```

*You have seen that the resource is protected by a policy in the constructor.*

So to delete a site type, the url is (for example) :

```
/organizations/7884ff47-afb7-48da-ac71-9b5ccf8b0cac/site-types/76d1ca7a-057a-428a-bd56-2fae2de3166d
```

I would like to check if the relation exists between **organization_id** and **site_type_id**.

Where could be the best place to check that :

- in the controller ?
- in the siteType policy ?
- in a middleware on the route ? (<== my preference)
- .... or perhaps there is an option in the framework to check that automatically ?

I have a little preference to check that in a middleware. But not certain.

Answer (score 0):

After reading and re-reading the documentation, there is a native way in laravel to do what I wanted.

You just have to add "scoped ()" to the route so that the framework understands that it must check the relationship between the 2 entities present in the route.

Like this :

```
Route::apiResource('organizations/{organization}/site-types', SiteTypeController::class)->whereUuid(['organization', 'site_type'])->scoped();
```

And you must add the relation in the model "Organization":

```
public function siteTypes ()
    {
        return $ this-> hasMany (SiteType :: class);
    }
```

And if the relation does not exist then the framework returns a 404 automatically.

The doc here :
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-scoping-resource-routes

Really, I love this framework!